# Check if Google Play Service is up to date

Tags: smartphone, sony, sony-xperia

I have a Sony Xperia Z3 compact,  and when I trying to broadcast my video live on YouTube from Xperia , I sign in with Google+ account and I received "Error when trying to sign in, please check if Google Play Service is up to date",what to do? ... When I buy my phone I updated all applications.

Comment: Should probably be moved to http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you think ? or should...

Comment: Got the exact same problem, on the same phone. But mine is straight out the box. Did you ever get this working??